# Spark Avro to parquet writing null values in number fields

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, avro, parquet

I am saving a spark dataframe as a parquet file and the dataframe has rows built from an avro object. The exact code for the same is here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41491999/2440775

The challenge I am facing is, I intend to be able to have nulls when the integer fields are missing in the incoming data. Avro seems to allow that by using Union types, but when I do not specify default value or specify a default value of "null" in the avsc, I get errors like:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Field xxx type:LONG pos:7 not set and has no default value
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getDefaultValue(GenericData.java:984)
    at org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilderBase.defaultValue(RecordBuilderBase.java:135)

Or

Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Field xxx type:UNION pos:7 not set and has no default value
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.getDefaultValue(GenericData.java:984)
    at org.apache.avro.data.RecordBuilderBase.defaultValue(RecordBuilderBase.java:135)
```

If I write a default value of "0", the it saveAsParquet works well

I also tried changing the avro spec to have the "null" type first since the union picks the type of first element.

```
"type": ["null","long"], "default": null
```

This causes an exception as below:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Changing the order of long and null in avro schema leads to the below exception

Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Non-numeric default value for long: null

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a solution as such, but found a workaround. The way I am building Row from the avro object is by creating a list from the avro object and then doing a Row.fromSeq on that. The workaround checks for the default value 0 and datatype of int or long. And in case of default value, adds null instead. So one will have to be careful with choosing the default values.

```
public static List avroToList(AvroData a) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        List l = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Schema.Field f : a.getSchema().getFields()) {
            Object value = a.get(f.name());
            if (value == null) {
                l.add(null);
            }
            else {
                switch (f.schema().getType().getName()){
                    case "union":
                        l.add(value.toString());
                        break;

                    case "int":
                        if(value == 0) {l.add(null);}
                        else {l.add(Integer.valueOf(value.toString()));}
                      break;

                    case "long":
                        if(value == 0L) {l.add(null);}
                        else {l.add(Long.valueOf(value.toString()));}
                        break;

                    default:l.add(value);
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
        return l;
    }
```

The avsc file has type information as below

```
"type": "long",  "default": 0
```